# How can I iterate this XML API response in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am getting XML response from one of the API which I have to iterate and extract required data from it. As I am working on XML response for the first time I am having some difficulties to do it.

Below is the XML response file:

```
<feed xmlns:d="http://schemas.example.com/a" xmlns:m="http://schemas.example.com/a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/">
    <title type="text">EMC_SR_NUMB</title>
    <id>
    http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/EMC_SR_NUMB
    </id>
    <author>
    <name/>
    </author>
    <link rel="self" title="EMC_SR_NUMB" href="EMC_SR_NUMB"/>
    <entry>
        <id>
        http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/EMC_SR_NUMB('204713171')
        </id>
        <title type="text"/>
        <author>
        <name/>
        </author>
        <link rel="self" title="EMC_SR_NUMB" href="EMC_SR_NUMB('204713171')"/>
        <category term="infra.infrae.EMC_SR_NUMBType" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:key m:type="Abc.String">204713171</d:key>
                <d:SR_NAME m:type="Abc.String">CLOV - 16RT</d:SR_NAME>
                <d:REGION m:type="Abc.String">GENERAL</d:REGION>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>
        http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/EMC_SR_NUMB('204713172')
        </id>
        <title type="text"/>
        <author>
        <name/>
        </author>
        <link rel="self" title="EMC_SR_NUMB" href="EMC_SR_NUMB('204713172')"/>
        <category term="infra.infrae.EMC_SR_NUMBType" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a"/>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:key m:type="Abc.String">204713172</d:key>
                <d:SR_NAME m:type="Abc.String">CLOV - 16RT</d:SR_NAME>
                <d:REGION m:type="Abc.String">TRENDS</d:REGION>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I have to extract following data:
1> `d:key`
2> `d:SR_NAME`
3> `d:REGION`

I am using javascript and jquery. Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery parse xml plugin:

You can get more information here:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

YOu need to use it like below:

```
  var xml = res, // YOur xml response will be accepted here.
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),



 $xmlDoc .find("entry").each(function(){
     console.log( $(this).find("content").find("m\\:properties").find("content\\:SR_NAME").text() ) ;
     //console.log( $(this).find("content\\:SR_NAME").text() )
    // console.log( $(this).find("content\\:REGION").text() )  
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, @Pra Jazz, I am getting the text but when I write $.parseXML( xml); I am getting nothing. Adding one more thing. The console output is "204713171CLOV - 16RTTRENDS" I need it in separate terms.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle of this

Comment: I might be able to play around it then

Comment: Truly I don't know how to add JS fiddle.

Comment: The console output is "204713171CLOV - 16RTTRENDS" I need it in separate terms.

Comment: Can we have d:key in saperate variable : var key = code.d:key ?

Comment: Edited answer accordingly can you try that.

Comment: Sure, let me try it.

Comment: try $(this).find("content\\:key").text() ifthis is not successful then  try $(this).find("content\\d:key").text()

Comment: Ohh you are from pune .. me too

Comment: Yes I am in Pune. I am getting blank (nothing) on the console. Is there anything to do with m:properties?

Comment: I am getting length: 0 at $(this).find("content").find("m\\:properties")

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using `DOM parser` like below

```
let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(s, "application/xml");

let mprops = doc.getElementsByTagName('m\:properties');
let res=[];
for (let i = 0; i < mprops.length; i++) {
    let o={};
    o.dkey = mprops[i].getElementsByTagName('d\:key')[0].innerHTML;
    o.dSRNAME = mprops[i].getElementsByTagName('d\:SR_NAME')[0].innerHTML;
    o.dREGION = mprops[i].getElementsByTagName('d\:REGION')[0].innerHTML;
    res.push(o);
}
console.log(res);
```

**DEMO**

```js
let s = `<feed xmlns:d="http://schemas.example.com/a" xmlns:m="http://schemas.example.com/a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/">
<title type="text">EMC_SR_NUMB</title>
<id>
http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/EMC_SR_NUMB
</id>
<author>
<name/>
</author>
<link rel="self" title="EMC_SR_NUMB" href="EMC_SR_NUMB"/>
<entry>
    <id>
    http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/EMC_SR_NUMB('204713171')
    </id>
    <title type="text"/>
    <author>
    <name/>
    </author>
    <link rel="self" title="EMC_SR_NUMB" href="EMC_SR_NUMB('204713171')"/>
    <category term="infra.infrae.EMC_SR_NUMBType" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:key m:type="Abc.String">204713171</d:key>
            <d:SR_NAME m:type="Abc.String">CLOV - 16RT</d:SR_NAME>
            <d:REGION m:type="Abc.String">GENERAL</d:REGION>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
<entry>
    <id>
    http://demo_url:3000/url/example.xsodata/EMC_SR_NUMB('204713172')
    </id>
    <title type="text"/>
    <author>
    <name/>
    </author>
    <link rel="self" title="EMC_SR_NUMB" href="EMC_SR_NUMB('204713172')"/>
    <category term="infra.infrae.EMC_SR_NUMBType" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/a"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:key m:type="Abc.String">204713172</d:key>
            <d:SR_NAME m:type="Abc.String">CLOV - 16RT</d:SR_NAME>
            <d:REGION m:type="Abc.String">TRENDS</d:REGION>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
</feed>`;

let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(s, "application/xml");

let mprops = doc.getElementsByTagName('m\:properties');
let res=[];
for (let i = 0; i < mprops.length; i++) {
    let o={};
    o.dkey = mprops[i].getElementsByTagName('d\:key')[0].innerHTML;
    o.dSRNAME = mprops[i].getElementsByTagName('d\:SR_NAME')[0].innerHTML;
    o.dREGION = mprops[i].getElementsByTagName('d\:REGION')[0].innerHTML;
    res.push(o);
}
console.log(res);
```

Refer to:

[DOM Parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: my mprops.length is zero. I am using the same code as you have done.

Comment: I am getting same schema which I have mentioned in my code

Comment: What code you're trying please add in the question. That might help.

Comment: When I am using your code I am getting "error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty"

Comment: You have no code in your question demonstrating what you're trying but an XML schema. Please add a minimal and verifiable example.

Comment: The problem can be in application of the solutions. As I was reading the comment threads on @Pra Jazz 's post you're getting a length 0 there also.

Comment: yes, whenever I am trying to acess tags with ":" eg. m:properties. The content I am getting is 0.

Comment: I am trying this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288232/javascript-xml-parser-how-to-get-nodes-that-have-in-the-name I think this may help me in solution

Comment: But in the given schema namespace is defined see the first line.

Comment: Yes But in my case namespace is not defined. How can I access that tag? I am not getting it.

Comment: You will have to do something like `xml.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://my.namespace', 'CreationDate')` refer to the link you provided above.

Comment: NameSpace is given in xml .Please check feed tag(1st tag). Now the problem is when we extract m:properties(each). That tag has d:key ,d:REGION, d:SR_NAME. That time the code dosen't know what the d namespace stands for. and giving an error  getElementsByTagNameNS is not a function

Comment: I have tested the code in firefox and chrome. Its working for the provided schema and also in stack snippets. I really don't understand why it doesn't work for you. :(

Comment: Same problem bro. I am unable to figure out why you provided code is nor working on my system.

Comment: The line in your code let doc = parser.parseFromString(s, "application/xml"); says ""error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162498/discussion-between-vibhor1997a-and-vaidya).